# OUTER JOIN of multiple tables in Pig

Tags: join, outer-join, apache-pig

I need to join multiple tables. The command that I am using is as follows:

```
G = JOIN aa BY f, bb by f, cc by f, dd by f;
```

To make it a full outer join, I added a `FULL` to make it:

```
G = JOIN aa BY f FULL, bb by f, cc by f, dd by f;
```

But it gives me a `mismatched input` error message. How should I make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the Pig [documentation](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#join-outer) :

> Outer joins will only work for two-way joins; to perform a multi-way
>   outer join, you will need to perform multiple two-way outer join
>   statements.

Comment: This page is what I usu. refer to. Do a ctrl+f for "Performs an outer join of two or more relations based on common field values" on that page. I'm beginning to think this might be a typo.

Comment: @Navneet : in a full outer join records are taken from both sides even when they don't match. The docs clearly states that full outer join expects two sides rather than three. The error message you get may be misleading therefore you might want to verify this by checking the corresponding junit testcase in the Pig source code: `org.apache.pig.test.TestJoin#testMultiOuterJoinFailure()` at
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pig/trunk/test/org/apache/pig/test/TestJoin.java

Answer (score 1):

You can use COGROUP statement to imitate full outer join. For example cogroup on using following two files

Decimal.csv

```
first|1
second|2
fourth|4
```

Roman.csv

```
first|I 
second|II
third|III
```

Pig commands:

```
english = LOAD 'Decimal.csv' using PigStorage('|') as (name:chararray,value:chararray);
roman = LOAD 'Roman.csv' using PigStorage('|') as (name:chararray, value:chararray);
multi = cogroup english by name, roman by name;
dump multi
```

Output:

```
(first,{(first,1)},{(first,I)})
(third,{},{(third,III)})
(fourth,{(fourth,4)},{})
(second,{(second,2)},{(second,II)})
```